# url is not loading in IE 11 using protractor 3.0.0

Tags: internet-explorer, protractor, cucumber, internet-explorer-11, iedriverserver

I am using protractor cucumber framework.
My problem is, the url which is working fine in chrome is not loading in IE 11.

protractor version: 3.0.0

config file:

```
var argv = require('yargs').argv;

exports.config = {
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  specs: [ 'SitFeature/*.feature' ],
  seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/selenium/IEDriverServer.exe'],

 capabilities: {

        'browserName': 'internet explorer'

        },

 params: {
        explicitWaitTime:60,
        isDataDriven:false
    }


};
```

please help to resolve

Comment: What does happen when you run this? Does IE load at all, do you get any errors etc?

Comment: run command "webdriver-manager status" on command prompt and see ie driver version

Comment: @JeffUK, IE is loading with selenium baseURL but after that, nothing loads.

Comment: @SureshSalloju, IE driver version is 2.48.0.0